# Cant install scikit-learn

Tags: python, python-3.x

I keep getting an error when I try to install scikit-learn,

```
    numpy.distutils.system_info.NotFoundError: No lapack/blas resources found.
```

that is the error I get, I can provide the whole output if that would be helpful.
I am using Python 3.8, Windows 10.

Making a new project usng 3.7.4, worked.

Comment: Do you have `numpy` installed?

Comment: Yes, I have numpy installed

Answer (score 0):

Are you install using anaconda or pip3 , also I recommend to create new virtual environment then install all dependcies inside it

Comment: I installed using pip, I checnged python versions and that worked.